# How to handle timer that won't terminate the application, just cancel the task then proceed next vb.net

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I'm trying to achieve to cancel the tasks when the timer elapsed. I have an internal function [CancelAsync] and have these code and I'm encountering error on  this line: Await Task.WhenAll(jobCancelledList) under the Tick method, maybe someone could help me figure it out what am I doing wrong on this? Another question, when the time elapsed, does it end there, what about the codes remaining on the Main method, will it still continue?

```
   Private WithEvents sysTimer As New System.Timers.Timer
   Private ReadOnly joblist() As ProcessingJob
```

'Handling Timer Elapsed

```
   Private Sub Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles sysTimer.Elapsed
    Try
        sysTimer.Stop()

        Dim jobCancelledList As New List(Of Task(Of Boolean))(joblist.Count)

        For Each listedJob As processingJob In joblist
            jobCancelledList.Add(listedJob.CancelAsync)
        Next

        Await Task.WhenAll(jobCancelledList)

        objErrorLogging.LogActivity("***       TASK TIMED OUT            ***")

    Catch ex As Exception
        objErrorLogging.LogError(_CLASS_NAME, System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.StackTrace, ex)
        objErrorLogging.LogActivity("***       TASK TIMED OUT            ***")
    End Try
   End Sub
```

'Calling Internal Functions

```
   Private Async Function setupGPJob(ByVal url As String) As Task(Of processingJob)
    Try
        objErrorLogging.LogActivity(String.Format("Starting processing task {0}", url))
        Dim processURI As New Uri(url)

        Dim streetCred As TokenCredential = Await AuthenticationManager.Current.GenerateCredentialAsync(processURI, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("UserName"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Password"))
        SyncLock _syncObject
            'Adds the necessary Credentials object to the list of allowed objects so that the service can be accessed.
            AuthenticationManager.Current.AddCredential(streetCred)
        End SyncLock

        Dim task As processingTask = Await processingTask.CreateAsync(processURI)

        Dim newJob As processingJob = task.CreateJob(Await task.CreateDefaultParametersAsync)
        newJob.Start()

        Return newJob

    Catch ex As Exception
        objErrorLogging.LogError(_CLASS_NAME, System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.StackTrace, ex)
        objErrorLogging.LogActivity("***        AN ERROR OCCURRED.         ***")
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

'Function to complete tasks

```
 Private Async Function doprocessing(ByVal docast As Boolean) As Task(Of Boolean)

    Try

        'Set up the list of processing jobs that need to be performed.
        'Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Started processing jobs at {0}" + vbCrLf, Now.ToString))
        objErrorLogging.LogActivity("Starting processing jobs")
        sysTimer.AutoReset = True
        sysTimer.Interval = (25 * 60000) '25 minutes interval
        sysTimer.Start()

        'sysTimer.Enabled = True

        Dim jobListSetup As New List(Of Task(Of processingJob)) From {setupGPJob(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("GPService1"))}

        If docast Then jobListSetup.Add(setupGPJob(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("GPService2")))

        Dim jobList() As processingJob = Await Task(Of processingJob).WhenAll(Of processingJob)(jobListSetup)


        'Run through the list and set them up to await for them to run to completetion
        Dim jobResultsList As New List(Of Task(Of processingResult))(jobList.Count)
        For Each listedJob As processingJob In jobList
            'AddHandler listedJob.ProgressChanged, AddressOf gpJob_ProgressChanged
            jobResultsList.Add(listedJob.GetResultAsync)
        Next

        'Await Task.WhenAll(jobResultsList)
        Await Task.WhenAll(jobResultsList)


        'Run through the list of Jobs and check for Errors or Warnings. Log those accordingly.
        Dim results As Boolean = True
        For Each listedJob As processingJob In jobList
            If listedJob.Error IsNot Nothing Then
                objErrorLogging.LogError(_CLASS_NAME, System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "Error encountered in processing Job", listedJob.Error)
                objErrorLogging.LogActivity("***        AN ERROR OCCURRED.         ***")
                results = False

            Else
                For Each message As JobMessage In listedJob.Messages
                    If message.Source = JobMessageSource.Service Then
                        If message.Severity = JobMessageSeverity.Warning Then
                            objErrorLogging.LogActivity("processing WARNING: " + message.Message)

                        Else
                            If message.Severity = JobMessageSeverity.Error Then
                                Dim newError As New Exception(message.Message)
                                objErrorLogging.LogError(_CLASS_NAME, System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name, "Error encountered in processing Job", newError)
                                objErrorLogging.LogActivity("***        AN ERROR OCCURRED.       ***")
                                results = False

                            End If
                        End If

                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next

        Return results

    Catch ex As Exception
        objErrorLogging.LogError(_CLASS_NAME, System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.StackTrace, ex)
        objErrorLogging.LogActivity("***        AN ERROR OCCURRED.           ***")
        Return False

    End Try
End Function


Sub Main()

    Dim blnDelete1 As Boolean = False
    Dim blnDelete2 As Boolean = False


    Try
        objErrorLogging.LogActivity("--        PROGRAM STARTS         --")

        'Get  data into our  DB
        blnDelete1 = import1Data()
        'Get  data into out  DB
        blnDelete2 = import2Data()



        'Do the Processing, set flag to True if run casts, o.w. set to False.
        If doprocessing(blnDelete2).Result Then
            objErrorLogging.LogActivity("processing operations successfully run to completion")

            System.GC.Collect()

            'Wait for app to let go of files
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)

            If blnDelete1 Then File.Delete(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FilePath1"))
            If blnDelete2 Then File.Delete(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FilePath2"))

        Else
            objErrorLogging.LogActivity("processing operations failed to run to completion.  TO THE LOG FILES!")

            System.GC.Collect()

            'Wait for app to let go of files
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)

            If blnDelete1 Then File.Delete(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FilePath1"))
            If blnDelete2 Then File.Delete(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FilePath2"))

        End If

        'Console.WriteLine("Done")
        'Console.ReadLine()


    Catch ex As Exception
        'Console.WriteLine(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.DeclaringType.Name + vbCrLf + System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.Name + vbCrLf + ex.ToString)
        objErrorLogging.LogError(_CLASS_NAME, System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex.StackTrace, ex)
        objErrorLogging.LogActivity("***        AN ERROR OCCURRED.       END IMPORT DATA WITH ERROR         ***")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Errors I've encountered:

[image]

[image]

Comment: *"Another question"*. Nope. SO requires that you ask one specific question at a time, so we can provide one specific answer. If you have multiple questions, post them separately, each with all the information relevant to that question and only the information relevant tot hat question.

Comment: *"I'm encountering error"*. What error? It's never enough to tell us that an error has occurred. You would also have been told why it has occurred and you need to pass that diagnostic information on to those whom you want to diagnose it for you. It looks like the error message would have told you explicitly that you can't use `Await` in a method not declared `Async`. Given that you already have another method that is declared `Async`, what part of that do you not understand?

Comment: @Ann You might be interested in this Microsoft article: [Cancel Async Tasks after a Period of Time (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-async-tasks-after-a-period-of-time).

Comment: @jmcilhinney, sorry, I've updated my query. I posted the errors I've encountered.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I saw that article too. But apparently I cannot touch the internal code, it's given to me that way, so I can only call their cancel method to cancel the job. I need to incorporate the cancel function on the timer but I need to make sure the programs goes on after it logs the error when timer elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in the comments, the error message tells you exactly what to do. If you want to use `Await` in a method then that method must be declared `Async`. There's a bit of a twist in this case. Normally, all `Async` methods are functions. If you have synchronous methods like this:

```vb
Public Sub DoSomething()
    '...
End Sub

Public Function GetSomething() As SomeType
    '...
End Function
```

then the asynchronous equivalents would look like this:

```vb
Public Async Function DoSomething() As Task
    '...
End Function

Public Async Function GetSomething() As Task(Of SomeType)
    '...
End Function
```

That would suggest that, in your case, your method should become a `Function` with a return type of `Task`. You can't do that though, because your method is an event handler and event handlers MUST be a `Sub`. This is the one and only scenario where you use `Async Sub`, i.e. when you want to use `Await` inside an event handler:

```vb
Private Async Sub Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs) Handles sysTimer.Elapsed
```